# Multiply each row by a variable contained within that row to expand the dimensions of the dataframe

Tags: r

I want to multiply each row in a dataframe by X times as defined by a value within the row.

Data:

```
df <- expand.grid(var1 = 1:3, var2 = 1:3)
df$repeatme = c(2, 3, 11, 6, 14, 1, 7, 8, 30)
```

The multiplying factor is to be determined by the `repeatme` variable.

Therefore, I want to multiply :

- row 1 ... 2 times (because `repeatme` == 2);
- row 2 ... 3 times (because `repeatme` == 3);
- row 3 ... 11 times (because `repeatme` == 11);
- etc.

Desired Output:

```
  var1 var2 repeatme
1    1    1        2
2    1    1        2
3    2    1        3
4    2    1        3
5    2    1        3
6    3    1       11
7    3    1       11
8    3    1       11

         ...
```

**EDIT**

To be clear, I'm not asking how to multiply variables within rows! I want to alter the structure/dimensions of the dataframe by multiply the rows themselves!

Comment: `df$var ^ df$repeat`?

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're asking. Are you sure your data and desired output match up?

Comment: there are many duplicates of this question already on SO - saying you want to "duplicate" or "replicate" the rows would be a better search term than "multiply"

Comment: @SamFirke already flagged as duplicate, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[rep(1:nrow(df), times = df$repeatme), ]
```